# How can i have same height and width of the div as bootstrap panel-body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am displayin logs that are coming from server consistently , So i have fixed height and width for the div that has `ng-repeat` directive so i can implement scroll bar to the screen. Now problem is on differnet screen resolutions fixed height and width is off from bootstrap `.panel-body`. How can i have same height and width as `panel-body` of the div even when screen resolutions changes ?

main.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="display-logs" scroll-bottom="event">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li ng-repeat="message in event track by $index" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

main.css

```
.display-logs {
    height: 530px;
    width: 1075px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport height and viewport width properties.

```
.display-logs {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: i want to have scroll both vertical and horizontal because message width could be larger then fixed width , by the way with your css rules text is going out of panel-body